# Constructing chain homotopy equivalence related to mapping cones

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

## Problem

(Weibel, *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, **Exercise 1.5.8**) Given a map $f\colon B\to C$ of complexes, let $v$ denote the inclusion of $C$ into $\operatorname{cone}(f)$. Show that there is a chain homotopy equivalence $\operatorname{cone}(v)\to B[-1]$. This equivalence is the algebraic analogue of the topological fact that for any map $f\colon K\to L$ of (topological) cell complexes the cone of the inclusion $L\subseteq Cf$ is homotopy equivalent to the suspension of $K$.

## Thoughts

First I need to determine $\operatorname{cone}(v)$. Note that $\operatorname{cone}(v)_n=C_{n-1}\oplus\operatorname{cone}(f)_n=C_{n-1}\oplus B_{n-1}\oplus C_n$. The differential operator $d\colon(c_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_n)\mapsto(-dc_{n-1},-db_{n-1},dc_n-c_{n-1}-fb_{n-1})$. (The sign convention of the mapping cone of $f\colon B\to C$ in Weibel's book is $d(b,c)=(-db,dc-fb)$). I guess that $\phi\colon B[-1]\to\operatorname{cone}(v),b_{n-1}\mapsto(fb_{n-1},-b_{n-1},0)$ and $\psi\colon\operatorname{cone}(v)\to B[-1],(c_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_n)\mapsto b_{n-1}$ or something like would serve for the homotopy equivalence, but $\phi$ isn't a chain mapping as defined! It seems that we should multiply something like $(-1)^n$ in terms, but it seems unnatural to me to do this because there's no geometric reason to do that!

Any help? Thanks!

## Remark

After some blind search work, I found that $\phi\colon B[-1]\to\operatorname{cone}(v),b_{n-1}\mapsto((-1)^{n-1}fb_{n-1},(-1)^nb_{n-1},0)$ and $\psi\colon\operatorname{cone}(v)\to B[-1],(c_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_n)\mapsto(-1)^nb_{n-1}$ should work: $\psi\phi=\mathrm{id}$, and $\phi\psi=ds+sd$, where $s\colon(c_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_n)\mapsto(-c_n,0,0)$.

Comment: In homological algebra, signs are sometimes unavoidable. Have you tried pushing ahead anyway?

Comment: @ZhenLin Maybe I was too lazy. Through a blind-search work (by guessing the grading, etc), I got a solution, but the geometric meaning is still unclear to me. For example, if $f$ corresponds to the embedding $S^1\to\overline{D^2}$, I cannot figure out where $s$ arise from geometrically.